# Table row behaving like a link

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, html-table

I've this code:

```
$('.table-striped tr').click( function() {
    var link = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    if(link != 'undefined') {
        window.location = link;
    }
}).hover( function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});
```

And it's working well (the `<a>` is hidden). I've also a nice CSS rule for `td:hover` that highlight the whole row.

What I miss now is:

- The right click to be able to "open in new tab/window"
- Middle Click

Do you know how to do it?

Comment: As far as I know, you're not going to be able to emulate that, as it's reserved for anchor tags within the browser. The only thing I would recommend as a complete guess would be to try adding an "href" attribute to your tr

Comment: I suggest using real links & css grid/flex to emulate table layout. Alternatively - still using links - set their display to `table-row`.

Answer (score 0):

The context menu and middle click action are default behaviors of browsers on links (`<a/>`). So in general you cannot simulate this behavior on other elements. But you could get close with some JavaScript.

For instance, to open a link in a new tab on middle click (like most browsers do per default), use this event:

```
$("#foo").live('click', function(e) { 
    if (e.which == 2) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // open new tab/window
        window.open('path');
    }
});
```

The context menu is a bigger problem, because it'll be hard (impossible) to make it look like the original, but you could create your own. There are several jQuery plugins for this. Just [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery%20context%20menu).